# Complete the days of weekdays in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long pandas dataframe with some days missing, what's the simplest way to add the missing days of weekdays(Mon-Fri)?

Now:

```
date              count1   count2
2021-01-18         3         4
2021-01-19         1         2
2021-01-22         1         0
2021-01-26         4         3
2021-01-27         2         3
2021-01-28         2         0
2021-01-29         0         2
```

Expected:

```
date              count1   count2
2021-01-18         3         4
2021-01-19         1         2
2021-01-20         0         0
2021-01-21         0         0
2021-01-22         1         0
2021-01-25         0         0
2021-01-26         4         3
2021-01-27         2         3
2021-01-28         2         0
2021-01-29         0         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your `date` is `datetime`, you can do this using `resample`:

```
# Set index of df to date and resample all rows to include missing days. 
# Replace all `nan` with 0.
>>> df.set_index('date').resample('D').asfreq().fillna(0)

# Create a mask to identify Saturday & Sunday
>>> m1 = df.index.strftime('%A').isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])

# Filter Sat/Sun.
>>> df[~m1]

            count1  count2
date
2021-01-18     3.0     4.0
2021-01-19     1.0     2.0
2021-01-20     0.0     0.0
2021-01-21     0.0     0.0
2021-01-22     1.0     0.0
2021-01-25     0.0     0.0
2021-01-26     4.0     3.0
2021-01-27     2.0     3.0
2021-01-28     2.0     0.0
2021-01-29     0.0     2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try asfreq with parameter B for business days

```
 df=df.asfreq('B').fillna(0)df=df.asfreq('B').fillna(0)
 for key, item in df.iterrows():
     print(key,item)
```

Answer (score -1):

`df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)`